# Getting error message while calculating rmse in a time series analysis

Tags: r, keras, time-series

I am trying to replicate this example of time series analysis in R using `Keras` (see [Here](https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/)) and unfortunately I am receiving error message while computing first average rmes

```
coln <- colnames(compare_train)[4:ncol(compare_train)]
cols <- map(coln, quo(sym(.)))
rsme_train <-
  map_dbl(cols, function(col)
    rmse(
      compare_train,
      truth = value,
      estimate = !!col,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )) %>% mean()

rsme_train
```

Error message:

> Error in is_symbol(x) : object '.' not found

There are some helpful comments at the bottom of the post but new version of `dplyr` doesn't help really. Any suggestion how to get around this?

Comment: `sym() ->These functions take strings as input and turn them into symbols`. You did not quote your dot, so this is no string.

Comment: Thanks Markus but same error comes back with the quoted version!

Comment: This might be all wrong, but do you need to use `toString()` around the `.`? I have a hard time following the code without going through some of the example link.

Comment: Not helpful larsoevlisen. Again same error but many tanks for trying. The error is now from `rsme_train <-` onwards but it is the same error!

Comment: i had this exact same question! do you know if this originates from here? blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem, so here's a solution that is close to the original code.

The transformation for `cols` is not necessary, because `!!` works with the character vector already. You can change the code to

```
coln <- colnames(compare_train)[4:ncol(compare_train)]
rsme_train <-
    map_df(coln, function(col)
        rmse(
            compare_train,
            truth = value,
            estimate = !!col,
            na.rm = TRUE
        )) %>% 
    pull(.estimate) %>%
    mean()

rsme_train
```

You might also want to check for updates of `tidyverse`, just to be sure.

Comment: i had this exact same question! do you know if this originates from here? https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/

Comment: there is a similar portion of code in the same tutorial that also doesnt work: coln <- colnames(compare_test)[4:ncol(compare_test)]
cols <- map(coln, quo(sym(.)))
rsme_test <-
  map_dbl(cols, function(col)
    rmse(
      compare_test,
      truth = value,
      estimate = !!col,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )) %>% mean()

rsme_test