# R: Error in is_symbol(x) : object '.' not found (keras)

Tags: r, keras, neural-network, time-series, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow the R tutorial over here on neural networks (lstm) and time series: https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/

I decided to create my own time series data ("y.mon") for this tutorial (the same format and the same variable names) :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(forcats)
library(timetk)
library(tidyquant)
library(tibbletime)
library(cowplot)
library(recipes)
library(rsample)
library(yardstick) 
library(keras)
library(tfruns)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibbletime)
library(timetk)

index = seq(as.Date("1749/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")


index <- format(as.Date(index), "%Y/%m/%d")

value <- rnorm(97520,27,2.1)

final_data <- data.frame(index, value)

y.mon<-aggregate(value~format(as.Date(index),
                              format="%Y/%m"),data=final_data, FUN=sum)

y.mon$index = y.mon$`format(as.Date(index), format = "%Y/%m")`
y.mon$`format(as.Date(index), format = "%Y/%m")` = NULL


y.mon %>%
  mutate(index = paste0(index, '/01')) %>%
  tk_tbl() %>%
  mutate(index = as_date(index)) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = index) ->  y.mon
```

From here on, I follow the instructions in the tutorial (replacing the "sun_spots data" with "y.mon". Everything works fine until this point (I posted a question yesterday that got closed for being too detailed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527230/r-error-in-is-symbolx-object-not-found-keras - the code can be followed from the rstudio tutorial) :

```
#ERROR
coln <- colnames(compare_train)[4:ncol(compare_train)]
cols <- map(coln, quo(sym(.)))
rsme_train <-
  map_dbl(cols, function(col)
    rmse(
      compare_train,
      truth = value,
      estimate = !!col,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )) %>% mean()

rsme_train
Error in is_symbol(x) : object '.' not found
```

I found another stackoverflow post which deals with a similar problem:[Getting error message while calculating rmse in a time series analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594095/getting-error-message-while-calculating-rmse-in-a-time-series-analysis)

According to this stackoverflow post, this first error can be resolved like this:

```
coln <- colnames(compare_train)[4:ncol(compare_train)]
rsme_train <-
    map_df(coln, function(col)
        rmse(
            compare_train,
            truth = value,
            estimate = !!col,
            na.rm = TRUE
        )) %>% 
    pull(.estimate) %>%
    mean()

rsme_train
```

However, the following section of the tutorial has a similar section in which the same error persists even after applying the corrections:

```
    compare_test %>% write_csv(str_replace(model_path, ".hdf5", ".test.csv"))
    compare_test[FLAGS$n_timesteps:(FLAGS$n_timesteps + 10), c(2, 4:8)] %>% print()

cols <- map(coln, quo(sym(.)))
    rsme_test <-
      map_dbl(cols, function(col)
        rmse(
          compare_test,
          truth = value,
          estimate = !!col,
          na.rm = TRUE
        )) %>% mean()
    
    rsme_test
    
    #errors:
    Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
      object 'model_path' not found
    Error in is_symbol(x) : object '.' not found
```

These errors are preventing me from finishing the rest of the tutorial.
Can someone please show me how to fix these?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you loading all those packages?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! They are all required for the tutorial

Comment: They don't seem to be used here (not all of them) , it will help you solve your problem if you know what packages are actually involved. Also don't ask me to install a bunch of  unneeded packages to help you.  I think the obvious question is: what is it that you think the '.' is representing?   Clearly R does not know, so if you can tell it that, things will work better.

Comment: Sorry - to get to the point in this tutorial where i need help in, many of those packages are required. I just wanted to make this post as reproducible as possible. I can remove them in this question if you would like.

Comment: Part of learning is really understanding what is happening in your code.  Creating a minimal example will both help you understand but also isolate where the problem is.  I will say one thing which is that a lot has changed in rlang since 2018 so it would not surprise me if a lot of changes are needed. Also what happens when you make the changes to the last code block? Such as using pull(.estimate)?

Comment: For this same problem, I posted a lengthy (minimal example) question with the full code and it got removed yesterday. I tried to post a shorter version of the same question. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `coln` in `map_dbl` :

```
rsme_test <- map_dbl(coln, function(col)
    rmse(
      compare_test,
      truth = value,
      estimate = !!col,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )) %>% mean()
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I could not reach to this step due to errors from the line above:

Comment: # build a dataframe that has both actual and predicted values
for (i in 1:nrow(pred_test)) {
     varname <- paste0("pred_test", i)
     compare_test <-
         mutate(compare_test,!!varname := c(
             rep(NA, FLAGS$n_timesteps + i - 1),
             pred_test[i,],
             rep(NA, nrow(compare_test) - FLAGS$n_timesteps * 2 - i + 1)
         ))
}
 
 compare_test %>% write_csv(str_replace(model_path, ".hdf5", ".test.csv"))
Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  object 'model_path' not found

Comment: coln <- colnames(compare_test)[4:ncol(compare_test)]
cols <- map(coln, quo(sym(.)))
Error in is_symbol(x) : object '.' not found

Comment: Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
 rsme_test <- map_dbl(coln, function(col)
     rmse(
         compare_test,
         truth = value,
         estimate = !!col,
         na.rm = TRUE
    )) %>% mean()
Error: Result 1 must be a single double, not a vector of class `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` and of length 3
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is fair to ask us to run the entire tutorial for you. Each post should contain only one specific question. Reading your post I thought you are stuck at `rsme_test` step hence I answered for that part. I am not aware of what happens before or after that part.

Comment: if you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644940/r-error-optimization-resulting-in-unused-argumentx thank you!